# How do I indent all lines text when I have a background image?

Tags: css

This seems simple, but I can't seem to get it to work as I wish:

My CSS:

```
.widget_box_fill {
display: block;
float: left;
clear: left;
width: 620px;
margin:0px 0px 0px 30px;
padding: 20px 0;
background: url(../images/tabbed_bg.jpg)  no-repeat;
background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

Try as I might, I can't seem to leave the image in place and indent all lines of text.

Comment: Add an element that just contains the text inside your current element which has the background, then add padding/margin to the contained element to indent the text.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `padding: 20px 0;` which means your left and right are padding 0.

Try using `padding:20px;` which will put it on all sides.

If you want it just on one side, try `padding-left:20px;`

Comment: Yep, the background will be on the element and padding is on the **inside** of the element.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to change padding and leave the background in the same position.

If so, you can try: `background-origin: border-box;`